# What else can EMP grenades and bombs damage beside robotic enemies?

Tags: xcom-2

So I just launched an EMP Bomb against a Sectopod that was next to an Advent Shieldbearer (shields deployed on himself and the Sectopod) and an alien relay.

Not only did the EMP damage the Sectopod, but it also instantly removed the shields from both it and the Shieldbearer, and it also heavily damaged the alien relay and set it on fire.

Besides EMPs also do the following:

1. Heavily damage robotic enemies and reduce their hacking defense,
2. Remove Shieldbearer shields,
3. Heavily damage alien relays,

are there any other things that EMPs are good at damaging or disabling?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [XCOM 2 wikia page for EMP grenades](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/EMP_Grenade_(XCOM_2)), it looks like *only* robotic enemies are affected, but can cause them to shutdown in addition to damaging them:

> The EMP Grenade is a grenade in XCOM. EMP Grenades ignore armor when dealing damage. They only affect robotic units.
>
> The EMP Grenade also has a chance to cause shutdown on robotic units. This makes it a weapon of choice when dealing with sectopods, allowing XCOM squads a little more time to deal with the threats in the area.

However, the [EMP Bomb](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/EMP_Bomb_(XCOM_2)) has a bit more utility in that it remove the ADVENT shieldbearer shields from any enemies, among other things:

> - The EMP Bomb are the upgraded version of EMP Grenades
> - EMP Bombs/Grenades deal damage to Codex. It also can stun or disorient them.
> - Make robotic enemies easier to hack, reducing tech score by 10.
> - The EMP Bomb will also remove the shield granted by the ADVENT Shieldbearer energy shield on any target, regardless if they are mechanical.

From the EMP Bomb wikia, it looks like EMP grenades can also damage Codex enemies, though it wasn't explicitly stated on the EMP grenade page.

Comment: From my observations, it also affects Gatekeepers.